# How to use dark mode in SupportMapFragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

I'm using **SupportMapFragment** (class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment") for **map** in my code.

When I switch my app to **dark or night mode**, everything are in dark except map fragment.

Is there any way to use dark mode in SupportMapFragment?

Thanks.

I'm using light mode map

[image]

I want night mode map like below

[image]

Comment: share your code, what you done so far

Comment: Did you find anything?

Answer (score 18):

You can style your map using this styling api (night mode or any other style you want)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling

In the class where you have the GoogleMap object, you can use a style like this one:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/res/raw/mapstyle_night.json

They even have a nice preview editor to create this json:
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

#### Usage

```
MapStyleOptions style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_night);
GoogleMap mMap; // assigned in onMapReady()
mMap.setMapStyle(style);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still makes unloaded tiles white - which causes extremely unpleasant white flashes when the fragment loads.

Comment: @Mavrik Did you ever find a solution to the white tile problem?

Answer (score -1):

you need to add a `View` over the map with dark-transparent background:

```
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myActivity_mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/myActivity_mapFragmentDark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#55000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

so you can show/hide this view to dim the map:

```
mapFragmentDark.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

or

```
mapFragmentDark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me other option to dark a map. but I want to use dark map. I have attached screen-shots of map that I want.

Comment: AFAIK android-map doesn't support this feature currently. The only way is to dim it with the code below.